# How to write statement of purpose with study gap and unrelated work experience?

Tags: statement-of-purpose

I'm having difficulty in writing my statement of purpose for my MA political science. I had a degree in political science, then a 10yrs study gap. All my work experience are not related to my field of study. Currently I'm into content creation. Please how do I make my SOP look good

Comment: not sure why that is any different from anyone else: write why you want to join the program and what value you will bring to the program. https://www.northeastern.edu/graduate/blog/how-to-write-a-statement-of-purpose/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are confusing the Statement of Purpose (SoP) with other documents that might be required, such as a "Personal Statement".

The SoP should be forward looking, not making excuses for the past or explaining it. It gives your goals for the program you are applying for and for your career afterwards.

The CV details the past, perhaps including your work history. A personal statement can be a bit of a hybrid, explaining changing goals, perhaps. An introductory letter might do the same.

But use the SoP for its intended purpose. What do you intend to study at the institution you are applying at. What specialty, though some places that needn't be to specific (US). What career are you aiming for and how does the MA fit in to those plans.

Note that your situation isn't especially unique, especially for an MA. Be prepared to speak of the gap if asked, but your work history can be self explanatory, especially if it is related to your academic goals in any way. But even if it isn't, going back for further education and a career change is acceptable on its own.